Cannot figure out why it returns "Syntax Error" when visual studio detected no problems with the code
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class test(App):
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.label = Label(text="hello")
        self.window.add_widget(self.label)
        return self.window
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test().run()

So recently I've started to use kivy and been trying around with it. But for some reason the code below keeps returning syntax error and I don't know why.
Still really new to pythons so I apologise if the question sounds silly
Visual studio also detected no problems in the code so I am really confused.

Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

The provided code sample ran without errors for me in VS Code in  Python 3.11.9.  Besides the full traceback, please also indicate whether you are using a virtual environment, and if you have confirmed that VSCode is running  the Python interpreter from that virtual environment.

There is no syntax error in your code. What does your .kv file look like?

I apologise for the time wasted, but I must have accidentally messed with the terminal, leading to the error. When I reopened visual studio sometime later, it ran just fine. Sorry for the inconvience caused turns out I am just stupid.
